# Determining whether a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ to $P_{3}$ is isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have a linear transformation T: $\mathbb{R^{4}} \rightarrow P_{3}$ which is defined as $T(a,b,c,d) = ax^{3} + bx^{2} + cx + d$. I need to determine whether it is isomorphic. I know that for it to be isomorphic it must be both one-to-one and onto. If $ker(T) = \{\textbf{0}\}$ (where $\mathbf{0}$ denotes the zero vector) then $T$ is one-to-one. Also, if the dimensions of the two vector spaces in the transformation ($\mathbb{R^{4}}$ and $P_{3}$ in this case) are the same then $T$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

I know that the dimensions of these vector spaces are both $4$ (I think it is because their standard bases both include 4 vectors? Correct me if I am wrong). I am thinking then that I only need to show that $T$ is one-to-one then it will follow that $T$ is onto, and hence isomorphic.

However, I am having issues showing that it is one-to-one. For some reason I am getting confused and I am stuck.

What I have so far is

$$T(a,b,c,d) = 0$$
$$\implies ax^{3} + bx^{2} + cx + d = 0$$
and then I am lost on what to do next. I can't figure out how to solve the polynomial equation for $a, b, c$ and $d$. If I can show that they are all zero then $ker(T) = \{\textbf{0}\}$ and $T$ is one-to-one, correct?

I would appreciate it so much if someone could walk me through how to proceed and show that it is one-to-one.

Comment: Do you know a basis for $P_3$?

Comment: Good. Now, since that is a basis, what does that tell you about the equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much done. We have $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$. Hence $a=b=c=d = 0$. This is simply by definition of a polynomial. You're probably confusing the term "polynomial" with a "polynomial function".

By definition, a polynomial $f(x)$ in the indeterminate $x$ with coefficients from the field $\Bbb{F}$ is an expression of the form
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k
\end{align}
where $n \geq 0$ is an integer and each $a_k \in \Bbb{F}$. Or I guess if you want to be super formal, you can define a polynomial to be a function $f: \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \to \Bbb{F}$ such that the set $\{k \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 0}| \, \, f(k) \neq 0\}$ is finite.

Also, the zero polynomial is then defined to be the one such that all the coefficients are zero. So really, your problem is trivially solved by definition of "the zero polynomial".

---

Side remarks: comment is one says "$T$ is an isomorphism", not "$T$ is isomorphic".

In this case, I think it is pretty easy to see directly that $T$ is invertible with inverse given by $T^{-1}(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d) = (a,b,c,d)$; hence $T$ is an isomorphism. So, the question (because it is a very simple scenario) can also be done without appealing to the theorem you quoted.